# Using images directly in html tags by webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm novice to webpack and I was wondering is it possible to use images directly in html tags?
I was able to load images in CSS file  as background :

```
background: url("../images/dog.png")
```

But when I want to use it in img tag like this:

```
<img id="home" height='75px' width='75px' src="../src/images/dog.png" />
```

I got error:
Cannot GET /src/images/dog.png
This is my webpack.config:

```
            {
            test: /\.(gif|png|jpeg?g|svg)/i,
            use: [{
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: { 
                    name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
                    gifsicle:{
                        interlanced: false
                    },
                    optipng:{
                        optimizationLevel: 7
                    },
                    pngquant: {
                        quality: "65-90",
                        speed: 4
                    },
                    mozjpg:{
                        progressive: true,
                        quality: 65
                    }
                } 
            }]
        }
```

And the hierarchy of my project:

[image]

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your public folder create an `images` folder and in your html img tag just pass the path of your images folder:

`<img id="home" height='75px' width='75px' src="/images/dog.png" />`

if you want to use the image inside your js file or jsx use webpack import

```
import React from 'react
import dog from './src/images/dog.png'

// ReactJS like component and images imports.
const RenderDogImage = (props) => <img src={dog} alt='This is a dog' />
```

sand box without react: https://codesandbox.io/s/k08zx1xv03

Comment: Thanks for your reply.This worked just fine ! But I have two questions: 1- Is this method good for loading images? 2- How can I change images path to src/images not in public folder?

Comment: In which way you mean loading images ?

Comment: Can you please suggest a way not using React?

Comment: It doesn't has to be react, it's just an example all you need is to import the image as described with the import statement and use it wherever you like.

Comment: In your sass style you have to understand that everything will be compiled to css and all '/images/[name].[ext] will be placed in the public folder unless any further config, so keeping the images in public folder is a good to go, or if you want an explicit usage use the import method in your js files.

Comment: import dog from '../src/images/dog.png'
var homeImg = document.getElementById('home');
homeImg.src = dog;

Comment: That was the way I was using that image. But I got error again

Comment: Can you please share a brief of your code and what you are trying to accomplish in your question body.

Comment: See, The first method was working just fine but you had update your answer. Lets ignore your update and consider your first one. By considering your first answer, How can I change image address from public/images/dog.png to src/images/dog.png ?